# Django-cms page blank even after adding text plugins

Tags: heroku, django-admin, django-cms

Okay so I was able to do the ff:

- Install django-cms on and show the "welcome page"
- Go to admin page and choose a template.
- Add a page

but when i try to add a text plugin to a page and preview it. The page is still blank and it does not even show an error.

WHAT COULD BE THE PROBLEM?

UPDATE: When i use the front-end editor "edit mode on" I am able to add plugins. That's weird

Comment: Which cms version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I eventually realised that it was caused by my failure to click on the 'publish' button.